# AWS Lambda & SNS: Invoke Lambda cross-region

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sns, aws-lambda

I have a Lambda function deployed to several regions. I would like to publish a message to SNS that will invoke these functions.

Using aws-cli I've created the topics, given Lambda permission to talk to SNS, and create the subscriptions. The subscription appears to be created successfully, and I can see it in the AWS console. But, it doesn't work. The lambda function does not get invoked.

Comment: Have you added the subscription as the event source in the lambda function settings?

Comment: Thanks for the question @AssafLavie. I have not done this specifically but I don't believe it's necessary when invoking from SNS or S3.

Comment: To clarify, I can replicate this in a simpler example by creating an SNS topic with a single subscriber in a different region. In that case I publish a message to the topic but the function is never invoked. It seems permissions related but I can't see anything specific to going inter-region

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is `CloudFormation` based example. You have to add invoke permission for `SNS` to the `Lambda` functions:

```
{
    "Type" : "AWS::Lambda::Permission",
    "Properties" : {
        "FunctionName" : { "Fn::GetAtt" : [ "YourLambda", "Arn" ] },
        "Action" : "lambda:InvokeFunction",
        "Principal" : "sns.amazonaws.com",
        "SourceArn" : { "Ref" : "YourSNSTopicArn" }
    }
}
```

Then you need to subscribe your `Lambdas` to your `SNS` topic. This can be done via API call or through `CloudFormation`.

```
{
    "Type" : "AWS::SNS::Topic",
    "Properties" : {
        "TopicName" : "YourTopicName",
        "Subscription" : [ {
            "Endpoint" : { "Fn::GetAtt" : [ "YourLambda", "Arn" ] },
            "Protocol": "lambda"
        } ]
    }
}
```

If you're missing any of this, your `Lambdas` won't invoke. Source for the above information is the official blog article [Invoking Lambda functions via SNS](https://mobile.awsblog.com/post/Tx1VE917Z8J4UDY/Invoking-AWS-Lambda-functions-via-Amazon-SNS).

Comment: Thanks. Could you help me understand what's happening with this AssumeRole policy? I'm not using Cloud Formation so I don't know it well, but you haven't specified a resource in that policy so is that giving Lambda permission to assume any role? Any security downside to that?

Comment: I apologize for the first iteration not being entirely correct. You don't need the root role. Does the corrected example make more sense?

Comment: For the time being I created a policy with a wildcard resource. Unfortunately it hasn't helped. I had already given the Lambda a "PassRole" policy.

Comment: Yes, ok, so the Lambda role includes a policy for InvokeFunction. And when I publish a message to the topic, it does invoke the function in the same region as the topic. The problem is, it doesn't invoke the functions in other regions, even though I can clearly see their subscriptions when I look at the topic.

Comment: You need to change permissions on your Lambda functions in other regions to allow execution from your SNS topic via ARN. That's the problem you're facing. This is currently not possible via dashboard, only via API or CloudFormation.

Comment: I use aws-cli for provisioning. Here is an example of the permissions I'm setting:

```aws lambda add-permission \
--region ${REGION} \
--function-name ${FUNCTION_ARN}:PROD \
--statement-id sns-invoke \
--action lambda:invokeFunction \
--principal sns.amazonaws.com \
--source-arn arn:aws:sns:us-west-2:${ACCT_NUM}:prod-reducer-us-west-2```

This is giving the production topic the ability to invoke the PROD alias of the lambda function.

Comment: I prefer scripts to `aws cli`, they are easier to manage. What the `--statement-id sns-invoke` is that something you predefined somewhere? Can you rather inline the statement?

Comment: I use bash scripts. Do you prefer python or..? In this case my understanding is that we are passing "sns-invoke" as the ID of the statement created with that command.

Comment: Usually ruby. Your command looks OK. Can you paste the command you create the SNS subscription with?

Comment: Thanks for your help. It's a strange one. If I have to convert this to use in-region SNS topics it should work fine, but it's unfortunate. Here is the subscription:

```aws sns subscribe \
--region us-west-2 \
--topic-arn arn:aws:sns:us-west-2:${ACCT_NUM}:prod-reducer-${REGION} \
--protocol "lambda" \
--notification-endpoint ${FUNCTION_ARN}:PROD```

Comment: Thank you! I've found the problem. You can see it in the statement I pasted earlier: I have hardcoded the Topic name in that statement. I appreciate your help because I was afraid it was an AWS limitation and I wasn't looking for the problem in the code.