# Can AWS Lambda be used in conjunction with services in other regions?

Tags: amazon-web-services, lambda

I'm interested in using Lambda for a few projects I"m working on, however it's not available in the Asia Pacific/Singapore region we're hosting our stuff in.

Would it be possible to set it up in, for example, the US-West region (Oregon) and then get it to interact with infrastructure in other regions such as SNS and and a couple of SQS queues?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use API Gateway to create an endpoint for your Lambda Function and call it from any Region (or even from outside AWS).

Or, according to this answer ([AWS Lambda & SNS: Invoke Lambda cross-region](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35006556/aws-lambda-sns-invoke-lambda-cross-region)) you can create an SNS topic in your region and subscribe to it from your Lambda function and that should work.

Comment: That second option looks like it'd be perfect. I'll give it a try. Thanks!